# How can I set a default value for the picker when using Apple's ResearchKit?

Tags: ios, researchkit

I'm trying to use the answer format ORKValuePickerAnswerFormat to select from a long list of selections, but I am open to using a different answer format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up your task view controller, provide a defaultResultSource. This should return a default answer for that step. See http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKTaskViewController.html#//api/name/defaultResultSource